# How to install Awesome Font Locally with Bootstrap for Drupal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, drupal, font-awesome, drupal-8

I have a site with Drupal 8.7 and Bootstrap 3.4.1 in SASS.

I have created a Bootstrap SASS subtheme, I want to host Font Awesome locally.

I downloaded and decompressed the archive at this address :

https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself

In the directory of my subtheme :

```
/bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/fonts
```

If I go to my site, the Awesome Font does not work.

Here is the configuration of my subtheme :

`bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.info.yml` :

```
core: 8.x
type: theme
base theme: bootstrap

name: 'Bootstrap Subtheme Front Office Old'
description: 'A Drupal Bootstrap 3 based sub-theme.'
package: 'Bootstrap'

regions:
  navigation_collapsible_first: 'Navigation (Collapsible first)'
  navigation_menu_first: 'Navigation (Menu first)'
  navigation_notification_first: 'Navigation (Notification first)'
  navigation_logo: 'Navigation (Logo)'
  navigation_notification_second: 'Navigation (Notification second)'
  navigation_menu_second: 'Navigation (Menu second)'
  navigation_collapsible_second: 'Navigation (Collapsible second)'
  breadcrumb: 'Breadcrumb'
  header: 'Top Bar'
  sidebar_first: 'Primary'
  highlighted: 'Highlighted'
  help: 'Help'
  content: 'Content'
  sidebar_second: 'Secondary'
  footer: 'Footer'

libraries-extend:
  bootstrap/framework:
    - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/framework
  bootstrap/fontawesome:
    - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/fontawesome
  bootstrap/global:
    - bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old/global

libraries-override:
  private_message/notification_block:
    css:
      theme:
        css/private_message_notification_block.css: false
```

`bootstrap_subtheme_front_office_old.libraries.yml` :

```
framework:
  version: 3.4.1
  css:
    theme:
      css/style.css: {}
  js:
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/affix.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/alert.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/button.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/carousel.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/collapse.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/dropdown.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/modal.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tooltip.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/popover.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/scrollspy.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/tab.js: {}
    bootstrap/assets/javascripts/bootstrap/transition.js: {}

fontawesome:
  version: 5.11.1
  js:
    fonts/fontawesome/js/all.min.js: {}

global:
  js:
    js/bootstrap.js: {}
    js/back-to-top.js: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply run the drush command drush fa-download. This will automatically download the Font Awesome library and install it at /libraries/fontawesome. You can check the status report page of your Drupal installation to confirm that the Font Awesome library is installed at the proper location.

Check out the Drupal.org documentation on this link
https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/font-awesome-icons/installing-font-awesome-icons

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/24168095)

Comment: added essentials parts